# MongoDB null field or true/false

Tags: mongodb

On MongoDB, when we have fields such as "draft" (yes/no), "published" (yes/no), etc which is the best strategy? Create the field in all the records and put "yes"/"no" values or put the field just where exists?

```
posts: [{_id:1, text:"hello", draft:true},{_id:2 text:"world", draft:false}]
```

or

```
posts: [{_id:1, text:"hello", draft:true},{_id:2 text:"world"}]
```

Which is faster? It's for a large amount of data.

Best regards, João

Comment: What did you do to measure it yourself?

Comment: I did not measure the results myself because I could overlook something important and since I don't have much experience with MongoDB, asking here seemed the right choice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Faster for what? Omitting the field when the value is false will result in slightly smaller documents, which could result in a slight overall speed increase.

But omitting the field makes it harder to query for false, specially if you have a mix of omitted fields and explicit false values.

Notice what the different queries return with this sample collection:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("500eeb7c42d87d5d861e1219") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("500eeb8242d87d5d861e121a"), "b" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("500eeb8642d87d5d861e121b"), "b" : true }
> 
> db.test.find({b:true})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("500eeb8642d87d5d861e121b"), "b" : true }
>
> db.test.find({b:false})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("500eeb8242d87d5d861e121a"), "b" : false }
>
> db.test.find({b:{$exists:false}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("500eeb7c42d87d5d861e1219") }
>
> db.test.find({$or:[{b:false},{b:{$exists:false}}]})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("500eeb7c42d87d5d861e1219") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("500eeb8242d87d5d861e121a"), "b" : false }
>
```

Notice that the query you have to write if you have a mix of omitted and explicitly false values is more complicated and might lead to slower query execution.

Comment: so you say that complex queries will slow down the return of results?

Comment: Even if you omit the field it's still a simple query if you use `$ne`.  `db.test.find({b: {$ne: true}})`

Comment: @JohnnyHK, It seems like `{b: {$in: [false, null]}}` is a better choice (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/indexes/#using-ne-and-nin-in-a-query-is-slow-why).
I ran an `.explain` with a simple index on `b` which showed less scanned objects using `$in` instead of `$ne`.

Comment: An interesting side-note:  {'b': null} provides yet another difference: db.test.find({'b': null}) would find both documents where b exists (and is null) and documents where b doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the previous answers talked about speed, but I think the reason why you would not want to treat a FALSE response as a missing response is that all of your missing responses would be wrongly assigned to be FALSE. So, for example, if you somebody whether he is employed or not, if the person is employed by decides not to respond, you would treat that person as not being employed, which is an error.

Answer (score 2):

Either's fine and speed is likely about the same.  Including `draft:false` will increase your disk usage a bit but they're both valid approaches.  Only testing would reveal if any performance differences would be enough to matter to you.