# Null field or bool = true in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, boolean

Let's say I want some items in my games to be wearable, and others not. I could do it using either `{"wearable": true}` with `{"wearable": false}`, or `{"wearable": null}` with `{}`. The second solution looks clunkier at first glance but is probably a little more performative, yet performance is not the most important thing here.

Imagine we need 10 such booleans for each item: wearable, placeable, equipable, etc. Then it's not just more disk space, but also each document for a game item becomes bloated and not very nice to use. Instead, we could have these fields only where we need them. But then `{"wearable": null}` doesn't look very intuitive. It would be perfect if one could write `{"wearable"}` and it would mean the same as `{"wearable": null}`, but unfortunately there's no such thing. Perhaps, I'm missing something important that would be a better solution here.

So should I use boolean fields, null fields, or there's a different better solution here?

Comment: Note: I found a similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634601/mongodb-null-field-or-true-false) but none of the answers there respond to my question

Comment: You can use an array field as `game_attributes: [ 'wearable', 'placeable', 'equipable', ... ]`.